# How to update a field by incrementing the value in batch update

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

So far, I have tried updating balance table like below. Its works fine.

```
$values = array(
    array('id'=>10,'c1'=>101),
    array('id'=>11,'c1'=>102)
);
$this->db->update_batch('balance',$values,'id');
```

I would like to know how to update **field value = previous value + new value**, means, **c1 = c1 + 101** in update batch array. I found

> $this->db->set('c1','c1 + 101',FALSE);

would be helpful. But I've no idea, how to use that in batch operation.

I have tried `array('id'=>10,'c1'=>'c1 + 101')` but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can do this with update_batch too.

```
$data = [
         [
           'id' => 10 ,
           'c1' => '(c1+101)' ,
         ],
         [
          'id' => 11,
          'c1' => '(c1+102)' ,
         ]
    ];
   $this->db->set_update_batch($data,'id',FALSE);
   $this->db->update_batch('mytable',null,'id');
```

generated query :

```
UPDATE `mytable` SET c1 = CASE 
    WHEN id = 10 THEN (c1+101)
    WHEN id = 11 THEN (c1+102)
  ELSE c1 END
WHERE id IN(10,11)
```

Answer (score 0):

You try this

```
$this->db->set('c1', 'c1+101', FALSE)
```

to

```
$this->db->set('c1', '`c1+101`', FALSE)
```

Comment: Exactly What's the difference is in both statement.
a sign that isn't affect ?